# Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$error in C:\xampp\htdocs\liker2\dashboard.php on line 131

Tags: php, json

i got this error can anyone solved it before some time there is no error but today i got this error on my page

```
    if(isset($_GET['type'])){
if($_GET['type'] == "status"){
$beranda = json_decode(get_html("https://graph.facebook.com/$user->id/statuses?fields=id,message&limit=7&access_token=$token"))->data;
    foreach($beranda as $id){
        $status = 'isset';
    $status .= '
    <section class="status">
    <section class="image">
    <img style="-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 37px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 37px;
border-top-left-radius: 37px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 37px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 37px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 37px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;"src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user->id.'/picture">
    </section>
    <section class="name">'.$user->name.'</section>
    <section class="message"><span class="color">'.$id->message.'</span></section>  //// on line 131 /////
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id->id.'">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"></form>
    </section>';
    }
    }
```

Comment: I think Your `$token` is invalid.

Comment: **Add** the output of `var_dump($beranda)` to the post, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, obviously the returned JSON may not always contain the `error` property, so you should check against its existence before using it, like the following:

```
if (isset($user->error)) {
...
}
```

Comment: i have more error can you check this

Comment: @RiyazSaifi What is the error?

Comment: Undefined property: stdClass::$message i

Comment: can i send you my liker.php file

Comment: @RiyazSaifi But you don't even have any `message` property in your code! you need to also provide some information on that problem, Edit your question post and I'll take a look :)

Comment: you can also check my liker.php file http://www12.uptobox.com/d/vuyqbarfeyoy22kqseczyctbn5oitjobhc7deurct4grts7tdxffu7z5/liker2.zip

Comment: please sir can you fix this using team viewer please sir